# How to pass a java file name to a script file while saving the java file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I can call a script file(.sh) through External Tools Configuration in eclipse. but how can i pass a java file name to a script file while saving the java file in eclipse.

Comment: Open the configuration for the External Tools Configuration. One of its fields is parameters to be passed to the tool. Help for that field will tell you about all the variables that can be used, one of which is currently selected file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. will try the same and let you know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the configuration for the External Tools Configuration. Refer picture below.

[image]

1. Enter the name for the external tool configuration
2. Select the path for the script. Here I selected abc.sh
3. Select the path of the Java file(inside workspace) you want to pass to the script. Here I selected Test.java file present inside the folder `src` which is present inside the project `Test`. Note the prefix `${workspace_loc}` this is a variable which points to the current eclipse workspace. You can look other variable details by clicking on the **Variables** button.
4. Make sure the shell script file was executable if not make it so by executing the command `chmod a+x <Your script file path>`. Click on **Apply** button then **Run** button.

#### Here is my abc.sh file content:

---

echo "hello script from eclipse"

echo "Argument to this script is: "

echo ${0}

---

#### Output:

After Pressing run you will get the below result in eclipse **"Console"** View.

---

hello script from eclipse

Argument to this script is:

/home/chandrayya/abc.sh

---